# Proguard optimization

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I readed the proguard documentation like 10 times, but I really don't understand one thing: if I put

```
 -dontoptimize
```

Optimization will disable, but if I want a full optimization, I have to only remove

```
-dontoptimize
```

or I have to write this?

```
-dontoptimize
-optimizations *
```

Can I omit?

```
-optimizations
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to only remove `-dontoptimize`.

From documentation:

```
-dontoptimize

Specifies not to optimize the input class files. By default, optimization is enabled; all methods are optimized at a bytecode level.

-optimizations optimization_filter

Specifies the optimizations to be enabled and disabled, at a more fine-grained level. Only applicable when optimizing. This is an expert option.
```

So basically you cannot use both these options together as **-optimizations option is only applicable when you are optimizing.**

Example: If you use `-optimizations  "!foobar,*bar"`, it matches all names ending with bar, except foobar.

For more info check here https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/usage.html